# How to add automatic Date that updates upon opening in Latex

Tags: pdftex, datetime

I know there is a command called \today; this will show the date that the document is created.

But how do I set the date that can automatically update depending on the date of opening the pdf?

Comment: that would require some javascript and a pdf viewer which can handle it.

Comment: So, did you mean that it is impossible to handle it in Latex?

Comment: You can add the JavaScript with LaTeX but not everyone who opens the pdf will see an effect